# How to dynamic import web3 in next js

Tags: web3js

I'm using web3 in my project, due to its size I want to import in dynamically,

```
const Web3 = dynamic(() => import('web3'));
```

But I'm getting these errors under this `() => import(web3));`

```
  Type 'Promise<typeof import("/Users/mohan/Desktop/alter-wallet/node_modules/web3/types/index")>' is not assignable to type 'LoaderComponent<provider>'.
      Type 'typeof import("/Users/mohan/Desktop/alter-wallet/node_modules/web3/types/index")' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<provider> | { default: ComponentType<provider>; }'.
        Type 'typeof import("/Users/mohan/Desktop/alter-wallet/node_modules/web3/types/index")' is not assignable to type '{ default: ComponentType<provider>; }'.
          Types of property 'default' are incompatible.
            Type 'typeof Web3' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<provider>'.
              Type 'typeof Web3' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<provider, any>'.
                Type 'Web3' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<provider, any, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 3 more.ts(2345)
```

How can I resolve this?